# Installing packages in Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, numpy, installation, scipy, package

I'm brushing up on my Python and have recently installed ver. 2.7.9 on my Win7 64-bit PC. I tried installing a couple of packages (numpy 1.9.1 and scipy 0.15.1) but I get errors through the process. I ran:

```
> python setup.py install
```

from the folder of each package and although the setup script ran, neither of the packages got installed. I got the following errors:

```
numpy: Unable to find vsvarsall.bat
scipy: No module named numpy.distutils.core (???)
```

Note that I haven't tampered with the packages files at all, which I extracted from the .tar files available in the Python Package Index database. I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Use Pip if you can! It'll make installation easier.

Answer (score 2):

The go-to repository for Windows modules is [Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) site. He has both [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and [`scipy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) available. To install, download the appropriate `.whl` file, then run

```
pip install name_of_file.whl
```

to install the module. `pip` should have been installed automatically when you installed 2.7.9, if the command is not found, make sure you add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your PATH and restart the command prompt.

Comment: @Zack The wheels are on Gohlke's website

Comment: For python >2.7.9 you can also run pip with `python -m pip install name_of_file.whl`

Comment: @Kersten I'm aware of that, but there's no point in typing all those extra characters each time you want to run the command, if you don't have to.